# How to use nltk.parse.corenlp.CoreNLPTokenizer for stanford chinese segmenter

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, sentence

I am using the following code from the tutorial at: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.stanford_segmenter , trying to do Chinese sentence segment

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize.stanford_segmenter import StanfordSegmenter

seg = StanfordSegmenter(path_to_slf4j='/Users/edamame/Documents/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar', path_to_jar='/Users/edamame/Documents/jars/stanford-segmenter-3.9.1.jar')


seg = StanfordSegmenter()
seg.default_config('zh')
sent = u'这是斯坦福中文分词器测试'
print(seg.segment(sent))
```

However, I got the following warnings and errors:

```
/Users/edamame/workspace/git/chinese_nlp/venv/bin/python /Users/edamame/workspace/git/chinese_nlp/chinese_segmenter.py
/Users/edamame/workspace/git/chinese_nlp/chinese_segmenter.py:5: DeprecationWarning: 
The StanfordTokenizer will be deprecated in version 3.2.5.
Please use nltk.parse.corenlp.CoreNLPTokenizer instead.'
       :
    more errors ...
```

I am using `nltk-3.3`. Based on the warning, I should use `nltk.parse.corenlp.CoreNLPTokenizer` for the Stanford Chinese segmenter (i.e. convert above code to use `nltk.parse.corenlp.CoreNLPTokenizer` ) . However, I couldn't find any example on the website, has anyone done similar things before?